# How do I get the numbers out of a String?

Tags: java

So I am currently experimenting with Strings in a List and I want to parse the Integers out of the Strings.

```
`List <String> test = new LinkedList<>();
 test.add("Hello123")            //I want ["123"]
 test.add("123Hello456")         //I want ["123456"]
 test.add("123Hello 456")        //I want ["123, 456"]
```

But with that split function you do not get ["123456"] in line 3. You get ["123", "456"], which I do not want.

Does anybody have an idea how to solve this problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: is `Hello` only basis of split?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `x.split("\\D+")`, do `x.replaceAll("[^\\d\\s]", "").split("\\s+")`. The `replaceAll` removes everything except the digits and whitespace, and the `split` splits on the whitespace.